# Winning plan for black in this line of French Defense: Advance Variation Main Line

Tags: strategy, positional-play, french-defense, planning

I play the French Defense as both white and black. I often play this line with black suggested by Korchnoi if I am not wrong. I have found a way to prevent the sudden b4, via Bd7 (if 8.Rb1 Bd7 9.b4 cxb3 10.Nxb3, I can answer with 10...Ba4, pinning the queen and winning material).

```
[FEN "r1b1kbnr/pp3ppp/1qn1p3/2ppP3/3P4/2P2N2/PP3PPP/RNBQKB1R w KQkq - 3 6"]

6. a3 c4 7. Nbd2 Na5
```

The problem is, although I feel comfortable with the limitations white has in development, I do not often find a winning plan as black and I end up finishing by playing for a draw.

What are your thoughts as to what I could do here?

Comment: Your setup stops b4 but in exchange you release all the pressure you had on White's centre.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once stuff has settled down on the queenside, you may eventually castle there and create play on the other sector, with moves such as ...f6 or ...f5 Take a look at a few illustrative games that may help you understand how to put this into practice